# Force on Dielectric Sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, dielectric

I came across this problem while studying for my qualifying exams: A spherical conductor of radius $a$ is maintained at a fixed potential $V_0$ If a dielectric sphere of polarizability $\alpha_E$ is placed a distance $r$ away (where $r \gg$ the diameter of the dielectric sphere) determine the force on the sphere. Is it attractive or repulsive?

I have never encountered a problem involving force on a dielectric before, so I was not sure how to proceed. I solved for the potential outside of the conducting sphere and found it to be 
$$
\phi(r) = \frac{aV_0}{r}
$$
Thus, the electric field is 
$$
E(r) = \frac{aV_0}{r^2}
$$
This field will induce a polarization on the sphere so that it will interact with the conductor. But how to I calculate the force? I can't find any useful information in Jackson, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is a in the potential?

Comment: @user110503 sorry, it is the radius of the conductor. i fixed the statement of the problem.

Comment: Do you think it could be using the formula for the force on a dipole moment $p$ of $F = p\cdot \nabla E$ and we can calculate $p= \alpha E$? Although this does seem quite simple.

Comment: @user110503 I found the solution in a book of graduate qualifying exam problems and you are right, I guess it was that simple. If you post this as a solution I'll upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing on from $$
E(r) = \frac{aV_0}{r^2}
$$
we set the dielectric on the positive $z$ axis so that on this axis $$
\mathbf{E}(z) = \frac{aV_0}{z^2} \hat{\mathbf{z}}.
$$
Since $z \gg$ the dielectric diameter, the dipole approximation is valid. The dipole moment is $$ 
\mathbf{p} = \alpha_E \frac{aV_0}{r^2} \hat{\mathbf{z}}.
$$
The force on a dipole $\mathbf{p}$ in an electric field $\mathbf{E}$ is $\mathbf{p} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{E}$, which in our case is
$$
 \alpha_E \frac{aV_0}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left ( \frac{aV_0}{z^2} \hat{\mathbf{z}} \right )\Bigg|_{r} = -2\alpha_E\frac{a^2V_0^2}{r^5}\hat{\mathbf{z}}
$$
If $\alpha_E > 0$ this force is attractive, and it is repulsive otherwise.